# jqplot meter gauge issue: c.jqplot is undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

anyone experienced this? I am new to this so I am not sure exactly what is going on here. But I am trying to use jqplot's meter gauge per documentation and it doesn't seem to be working. I can create bar, line, etc graphs just fine.

include the necessary script link (as well as the others needed):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../plugins/jqplot.meterGaugeRenderer.min.js"></script>
```

markup

```
<div id='chart6'></div>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    plot6 = $.jqplot('chart6', [[18]], {
        title: 'Network Speed',
        seriesDefaults: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.MeterGaugeRenderer,
            rendererOptions: {
                label: 'MB/s'
            }
        }
    });
});
```

firebug says:

TypeError: c.jqplot is undefined  - inside the meterGaugeRender js file.

any help would be greatly appreciate as always.

Comment: would you be able to provide a live example?

Comment: was able to resolve; user error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you did not include the basic jqPlot library, just the meter gauge add on.